# How do I find out the source from where the website gets its information

Tags: php, dynamic, web

As I go through pages of pages from a website filled with information that I know are coming from a database somewhere on the backend, is there a way to find out the php link to where this information is stored through chrome dev tool so I can extract them into an excel sheet? Is this possible?

Comment: If the website programmers have done a good job, no.

Comment: Did you actually think this would be possible? Image the security and privacy implications if you were able to download anyone else's database simply by _"finding a url"_ using chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If front-end scripts recieve data from back-end servers via *AJAX calls*, you can, for example, see full HTTP requests parameters in the **Network** tab of **Google Chrome Developer tools** in Chrome browser (other browsers provide similar functionality).

Open Network tab of Google Chrome Developer tools and perform some actions on site. If your actions do not lead to opening another page, you will see some activity in your Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side language so you can not get this.
Of course, if the website is vulnerable and you can get access to the "code" then yes, is possible.